# Как настроить CodeBlocks + MinGW для работы с glaux?

Tags: mingw, c++, opengl

Здравствуйте. Изучаю С++ используя **CodeBlocks + MinGW**. Читая понравившуюся книжку по C++ добрался до работы с OpenGL.

Подключение необходимых библиотек к линкеру CodeBlocks'a производится в следующем месте:

> Settings/Compiller_compiler_and_debugger/Global_compiler_settings/Linker_settings

После подключения список Link libraries выглядит примерно так:

```
C:\MinGW\lib\libopengl32.a
C:\MinGW\lib\libglu32.a
C:\MinGW\lib\libglaux.a
```

После указания библиотек компилятор перестал ругаться и и запустил код. Но после открытия консольного окошка вылезает ошибка:

> "Точка входа в процедуру **auxInitWindowA** не найдена в библиотеке DLL GLAUX.DLL"

Смотрю в код примера, да есть такая функция **auxInitWindow()**, смотрю через какой-то плагин в TotalCommander'e на внутренности файла **glaux.dll**, а там нет записи **auxInitWindow**, есть например auxInitDisplayMode, но конкретно **auxInitWindow** нет. Скачал еще кучу файлов glaux.dll, смешно конечно, но убедился, что и в них нет этой функции. Хотя просмотрев содержимое **glaux.lib** обнаружил там _auxInitWindowA@4. Значит дело в glaux.dll или я чего-то не понимаю?

Покопавшись в инете не увидел подобных проблем ни у кого больше. И команда инициализации окна у всех выполняется без проблем. Пожалуйста, помогите справиться с этой проблемой.

---

Не могу запустить даже самый простейший код:

```
#include "afxwin.h"
#include "GL/gl.h"
#include "GL/glu.h"
#include "GL/glaux.h"

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    auxInitDisplayMode(AUX_RGB);
    auxInitPosition (0, 0, 500, 500);
    auxInitWindow ("Step1");  <---------- Осечка
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: http://www.opengl.org/wiki/MinGW. Вероятно нужна libglaux.a, но лучше не шаманить.

Comment: Т.е. проблема именно в подключении glaux.lib?

Comment: Не уверен (1) и вероятно (2). Ну и ключики не забывать. Для этой библиотеки `-lglaux`

Comment: @alexlz Можете поподробнее объяснить про ключики? А, то я вообще толком в этом не разбираюсь еще.

Comment: Я правильно понял, что **не подключается только auxInitWindowA()**, а все остальные aux... подключаются ?

Comment: @avp Вы все правильно поняли, т.е. если за комментировать строку

    auxInitWindowA( "Программа 1.1" );

то программа будет выполняться без всяких проблем, только будет видно одно окно консоли.

Comment: Попробуйте включить glaux.lib в список модулей линкера (сразу после всех .o)

Comment: @avp Я так понимаю это в настройках IDE CodeBlocks?
>Settings/Compiller_and_Debuger/Global_compiller_settings/Linker_settings

И добавить **glaux.lib** надо в конец списка модулей с расширением **.a**?

В общем добавил его. Список принял вид:

    C:\MinGW\lib\libglu32.a
    C:\MinGW\lib\libglaux.a
    C:\MinGW\lib\libopengl32.a
    C:\MinGW\lib\GLAUX.Lib

Но все та же ошибонька: 

> "Точка входа в процедуру auxInitWindowA не найдена в библиотеке DLL GLAUX.DLL"

Comment: Не знаю, как надо делать  в IDE. Всегда *сам* делаю Makefile. 

Если Ваша "*ошибонька*" вылезает на этапе линковки, то надо получить команду:

    gcc -o my-appl my-appl.o p1.o p2.o ... glaux.lib -L ... -l ...

glaux.lib должен присутствовать в списке параметров **как объектный файл** т.о. линкер будет его просматривать при разрешении ссылок **до** всех библиотек. Ведь вы утверждаете, что auxInitWindowA там есть.

Если же ошибка возникает при запуске модуля, то Вам действительно нужна динамическая библиотека (скорее всего именно GLAUX.DLL), содержащая auxInitWindowA.

Comment: Ну у меня оно собралось командой `i586-mingw32msvc-gcc gltst.c glut32.lib -lopengl32 -lglu32 -lglaux`, но при запуске под wine я получил `

err:module:import_dll Library GLAUX.DLL (which is needed by L"Z:\\v\\alex\\tmp\\a.exe") not found
err:module:LdrInitializeThunk Main exe initialization for L"Z:\\v\\alex\\tmp\\a.exe" failed, status c0000135
`

Comment: @avp Даа, мне нужно по изучать Makefile's. Но если на этапе линковки ошибки, как правило, отображаются в логе IDE, то эта ошибка лезет в отдельном окошке с кнопкой "Ок". И как я уже говорил, просматривал содержимое нескольких GLAUX.DLL и не находил там этой auxInitWindowA, но в glaux**.lib** такая штука имеется. 

Вообще все отличие .dll от .lib заключается только в том, что .dll приспособлена для обслуживания нескольких программ одновременно? Т.е. программе должно хватать и .lib файла, чтобы выполняться?

Comment: @alexlz А, как в этом случае указать на GLAUX.DLL ? И кстати glut32.lib в этом примере совсем не нужна, это отдельная библиотека подобная glaux, только для UNIX систем(так сказано в книге).

Comment: Вероятно должна быть в %path%

Comment: Ну скачал, положил рядом с exe'шником: `wine: Call from 0x7bc4aaa0 to unimplemented function GLAUX.DLL.auxInitWindowA, aborting
wine: Unimplemented function GLAUX.DLL.auxInitWindowA called at address 0x7bc4aaa0 (thread 0009), starting debugger...` Как в стихе: "Иши ты сам свои политбюры"

Comment: @alexlz Спасибо вам огромное, за то что проверили у себя. Теперь я точно знаю, что проблема не связана с какими-то моими настройками IDE, дело точно в этой библиотеке.

Кстати цитата из книги :)
> На практических занятиях используется среда разработки Microsoft Visual C++ на ПК под управлением Windows 95/98/NT. Все программы, рассматриваемые в качестве  примеров  в  лекциях,  и  ответы  к упражнениям  написаны  на  стандартном ANSI Си++  и  проверены  в  среде  Microsoft  Visual  C++  5.0  на ПК под  управлением Windows 98.

Мне остается только установить эту Visual C++ 5.0 на Win 98 и все! :

Comment: Зачем win98? У вас же винды, должно работать. Вы же не под wine (эмулятор виндов) их пускаете. С эмулятором мало ли чего может быть...

Comment: @alexlz Ну да все верно, я это так ^_^

Comment: Попробуйте вытащить auxInitWindowA из glut32.lib как отдельный файл auxInitWindowA.o, используя утилиту *ar* и линкуйте с ним.

    ar x glut32.lib auxInitWindowA 

Уточнить имя auxInitWindowA (как оно точно называется в архиве) можно утилитой *nm*

-

"err:module:import_dll Library GLAUX.DLL" - для запуска в wine эта dll действительно нужна. Если все что нужно из нее у Вас уже прилинковано, то просто подсуньте под именем GLAUX.DLL любую shared lib.

Comment: @avp Никогда не пробовал такое. Это нужно в консоли набрать? И что означает x?

Comment: х означает команду 'extract'. Набирать, естественно, в командной строке. 

Почитайте man-ы для ar, nm, ld, gcc, make, bash ... из *SEE ALSO* в них тоже много ссылок не полезное чтение.

Comment: @avp Сами пробовали? В glut32.lib водятся какие-то aux'ы?

Comment: Вытаскивать модули из библиотек (не dll) ? На \*nix неоднократно. На винде нет, но думаю ar из MinGW это делает. 

Если не получается, извините за некорректный совет.

Comment: @alexlz Ну я так понял это было сказано для glaux.lib как раз в ней лежит auxInitWindowA и auxInitWindowW. т.е. команда будет выглядеть так:
> ar x glaux.lib auxInitWindowA

Comment: @avp Вывел список имен из архива glaux.lib среди них обнаружил три очень похожих:
> _auxInitWindowA@4
> _auxInitWindowAW@8
> _auxInitWindowW@4

Ввожу команду:
> rw x glaux.lib _auxInitWindowA@4

rw пишет в ответ:
> no entry _auxInitWindowA@4 in archive

Наверняка я ввожу имя как-то не правильно?

Comment: Попробовал извлечь из архива все файлы. Написал просто:
> ar x glaux.lib

и он мне выдал:
> obj\i386\tk.obj: No such file or directory

Что бы это могло значить? Он запнулся на извлечении первого же файла?

Comment: Я нашел у себя какой-то libfl.lib в UnixUtils, вызвал ar x libfl.lib из MinGW\bin и получил находящиеся там .obj

-

По поводу "no entry" ar надо задавать имя **member (а не символа)** в библиотеке. Посмотрите вывод команды nm и определите в каком member находятся _auxInitWindowA@4 _auxInitWindowAW@8 _auxInitWindowW@4

Comment: @avp вот одна из строчек вывода команды [nm -A glaux.lib]:

    glaux.lib:obj/i386/glaux.obj:00000000 T _auxInitWindowA@4

Что здесь является member'ом?

Comment: @avp Я что-то совсем запутался. Зачем всё это? Нет glaux.dll?

Comment: c:/Documents and Settings/avp/src/tst $ nm libfl.lib
    
    libyywrap.obj:
    00000000 N .debug$F
    00000000 i .drectve
    00000000 t .text
    000a2306 a @comp.id
    00000000 T _yywrap

    libmain.obj:
    00000000 N .debug$F
    00000000 i .drectve

member-ы это libyywrap.obj, libmain.obj ...

Comment: @avp Ага, значит в моем случае нужный мне мембер это glaux.obj, причем полная запись выглядит так:

    obj/i386/glaux.obj:

Ввожу команду [ar x glaux.lib glaux.obj] опять пишет:

    no entry glaux.obj in archive

Ввожу [ar x glaux.lib obj/i386/glaux.obj] то же самое:

    no entry obj/i386/glaux.obj in archive

Видимо не судьба...

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте использовать  auxInitWindow().

Пробуйте создать самый простой проект [пример](http://www.firststeps.ru/mfc/opengl/r.php?1)

Comment: Попробовал самый простой проект. Опять вылезла та же самая ошибка. Вы то же используете **CodeBlocks+MinGW**?